# Reset Git branch 'Destination' with 'Source' except for one file in 'Destination'

Tags: git

Let's say I have to branches `Destination` and `Source`. They contain exactly the same files  - only with a different commit history. I must reset every file in 'Destination' to the state in `Source` while "copying" the commit history from `Source`. However, there is exactly one file (`file.ps1`) for which I must preserve the commit history as it is in `Destination`.

Is there any way to achieve this? From what I found so far the hard part here is preserving the history for the one file on the one hand and "copying" the history for the rest on the other.

EDIT:

Here is why I am asking for this.

Whenever we have to change a file in `Source`, we create a new feature branch from `Source`. So far so good.

In the past we created a pull request to merge the feature branch into `Source` and we then deployed the whole `Source` branch and tested on the target system. If the code had to be amended we did this in the feature branch and merged again into `Source`, tested etc.

If someone now created a feature branch from `Source` they potentially had faulty code in their branch.

Obviously the correct way is to deploy the feature branch to the target system, perform the tests, and, if the code needed corrections, re-deploy `Source` to revert back the changes. Then, when the code in the feature branch is working, merge via pull request into `Source`.

We have the situation now, that while every feature branch should have only changes (relative to `Source`) in the file(s) affected by the particular feature implementation, there are additional files affected.

Hence, I would like to bring back all feature branches to the working state of `Source` and then have all files for which the respective feature branch was created show all commits which have happened so far - as opposed to making one single commit with the latest code of that file in the feature branch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A given commit traces *one* history. No way to store *two* histories in one. But all this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to solve here? Why does this one file need a different history?

Comment: It's possible to rewrite the two histories and then put them back together, but I agree with @RomainValeri that maybe you should say why you want to do this since it feels like there should be a better way. If you must go down this path, we would need more information, for example: Do you wish to remove the one file's history from `Source` as well? And then how do you want the resulting history to look? All `Destination` commits followed by all `Source` commits (or vice versa), or should they be parallel histories with a merge commit at the top?

Comment: @RomainValeri, I added more details in my original question. Does this help you to push me in the right direction?